# How to remove numbers from a string column that starts with 4 zeros?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of names and informations of products, i need to remove the codes from the names and every code starts with four or more zeros, some names have four zeros or more in the weight and some are joined with the name as the example below:

```
data = {
    'Name' : ['ANOA 250g 00004689', 'ANOA 10000g 00000059884', '80%c asjw 150000001568 ', 'Shivangi000000478761'],
}
  
testdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The correct output would be:

```
results = {
        'Name' : ['ANOA 250g', 'ANOA 10000g', '80%c asjw 150000001568 ', 'Shivangi'],
    }
      
    results = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: Start by *not thinking of them as numbers, because they aren't*.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
testdf['Name'] = testdf['Name'].str.replace(r'(?:(?<=\D)|\s*\b)0{4}\d*',
                                            '', regex=True)
```

Or, similar to @HaleemurAli, with a negative match

```
testdf['Name'] = testdf['Name'].str.replace(r'(?<!\d)0{4,}0{4}\d*',
                                            '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                      Name
0                ANOA 250g
1              ANOA 10000g
2  80%c asjw 150000001568 
3                 Shivangi
```

[regex1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dSbWq8/1)

[regex2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/UDe6Qe/1)

Comment: This regex won't match the last item `'Shivangi000000478761'`. In a now deleted post someone proposed something like `[^\d]0{4,}\d*`, which seems to work for all cases.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly good point, then `r'\s*0{4}\d*'` or `r'\s*0{4}\d*$'`

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, I was the author of that deleted post, which had a small error, that I have now fixed & undeleted.

Comment: @mozway, your current pattern `r'\s*0{4}\d*'` does not seem to work on the test data, but the one you propose in the comments, `r'\s*0{4}\d*$'` does.

Comment: Finally got a minute to double check, I updated the regex

Answer (score 3):

you can split the strings by the start of the code pattern, which is expressed by the regex `(?<!\d)0{4,}`. this pattern consumes four `0`s that are not preceded by any digit. after splitting the string, take the first fragment, and the `str.strip` gets rid of possible trailing space

```py
testdf.Name.str.split('(?<!\d)0{4,}', regex=True, expand=True)[0].str.strip()[0].str.strip()
# outputs:
0                 ANOA 250g
1               ANOA 10000g
2    80%c asjw 150000001568
3                  Shivangi
```

note that this works for the case where the codes are *always* at the end of your string.

Comment: Good one, I have to say I read the initial question too quickly! +1

Answer (score -1):

try splitting it at each space and checking if the each item has 0000 in it like:

```
answer=[]
for i in results["Name"]:
    answer.append("".join([j for j in i.split() if "0000" not in j]))
```

Comment: In the future, I would verify that your solution works for the test case provided. This snippet doesn't solve the issue described because 1) `some [numbers] are joined with the name` so splitting the string only works in some cases, and 2) it should only remove codes that *begin* with four zeros; this code incorrectly removes `150000001568` which contains four zeros, but doesn't begin with them.